# How do I get more special vehicles in gta 5 story mode?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

How do I get more special vehicles in gta 5 story mode?

I only have an Elegy, I would also like the Zentorno and Turismo.

Answer (score 2):

Zentorno and Turismo are not special vehicles. You have to purchase them from the in-game website "Legendarymotorsport.net".